# Google Calendar recurring event on specific date

Tags: google-calendar

I just started to use Google Calendar. I would like to create an event that happens on the 4th of each month. I've seen that I can make an event that happens on Tuesday every 4 weeks, but that is not what I am looking for.

Is it possible to make an event recur on a specific date?

Answer (score 5):

I have done this many times, though only on Android. When you make a new event on Android, you go to Repetition and then type of repetition and then choose monthly, where you can specify a number day.

Edit: I just checked the desktop version for you, which works as well. When you make a new  repeating event, first set it on the start day, then check the **Repeat** box, choose a **Monthly** event, and the option to make it a **specific day** is a radio button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**2021-08-10 on the web interface**

- Start creating event
- "More options"
- Change "Does not repeat" to "Custom..."
- Set "Repeat every 1 month"

Their UI design was not great, this is one of the most important options, and it shows more hidden than less important things like "Every last wednesday".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Made perfect sense.  Thanks for the visual breakdown!

Answer (score 0):

This below method doesn't work too well for an event that occurs only once a month. But it does work! It works better when you want an event to recur 10 - 12 times on only specific days in the next couple week.

1. Create a Daily event that goes from the date of the first event to the date of the last event.
2. On each day you do not want the event. Click that specific event on the calendar and click "Delete event".
3. Select "This event" then press "Ok".

Comment: This does not really address the issue of automated recurrence.  It is also prone to user errors and in many use cases is likely more work than simply duplicating an event and modifying the date.   This makes more sense for a recurring event that has gaps (e.g.  Reccuring event skipped for a particular week because of holiday)

Comment: @BlindSpots I agree. For cleanup the title for this question should be modified so that it's not on the first page of results when googling for "Can Google Calendar repeat event on specific days?". A title suggestion for this is "Google Calendar repeat on specific day of the month". Then a new question can be created with the title that this question had, with the description in your comment, and the answer I put.

Answer (score -2):

On a mac laptop, when editing the event there's a More Actions dropdown menu to the right of the Save button. Click that and Duplicate the event. Then go to the date and change it to the date you need it to repeat on. It might be a little tedious as you need to all that for each month.